# performance about cpp function after bind with pybind11

Tags: pybind11

I write a test example using python_example of pybind11 in this repo:

https://github.com/pybind/python_example

and here is all the code in main.cpp

```
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/functional.h>
#include <pybind11/operators.h>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <random>

class TestCPPSpeed {
public:
  TestCPPSpeed() {
    auto t0 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    vec.reserve(capacity);
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i) {
      vec.push_back(uint32_t(random() % 5));
    }
    auto t1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    double elapse =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t1 - t0).count();
    printf(" alloc time elapse is : %.f\n", elapse);
  }
  double sumf() {
    auto t0 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    double s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i) {
      s += std::log(vec[i] * 1.0);
    }
    auto t1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    double elapse =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t1 - t0).count();
    printf(" sum time elapse is : %.f\n", elapse);
    return s;
  }
  std::vector<uint32_t> vec;
  uint32_t capacity = 1000000000;
};

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(python_example, m) {
  py::class_<TestCPPSpeed>(m, "cspeed")
      .def(py::init<>())
      .def("sumf", &TestCPPSpeed::sumf);
}
```

write a test python file : test.py

```
import python_example

obj =  python_example.cspeed()
r = obj.sumf()
print(" sumf is : ", r)
```

and I run this code like this:

```
pip3 install ./
python3 test.py
```

and the result is (run several times):

alloc time elapse is : 4648
sum time elapse is : 7423
sumf is :  -inf

but I bind the same cpp code using cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(cspeed)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
# add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} cppmain.cpp)
# add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED cppmain.cpp)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/include)
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    pybind11
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/pybind/pybind11
    GIT_TAG v2.10.4
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(pybind11)

if(NOT pybind11_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(pybind11)
    add_subdirectory(${pybind11_SOURCE_DIR} ${pybind11_BINARY_DIR})
endif()

pybind11_add_module(${PROJECT_NAME}
    main.cpp
)
```

the result is :

alloc time elapse is : 4553
sum time elapse is : 6898
-inf

this way is 10% faster than the first way, also the speed is same with pure cpp binary with no python bind.

why this happen?

Comment: How are you compiling the code in the first example? I can see in the second example you are using CMake, a build system, but it isn't clear what the first method is.

Comment: using this example  https://github.com/pybind/python_example
change main.cpp to the code in the first example
and run like this:

pip3 install ./
python3 test.py